# How to filter particular word from a particular sentence using batchscript?

Tags: batch-file

```
C:\a\controller2.log.2018-02-28:2018-02-28 20:20:59,092 # [XLProcessContextImpl.126591.end_of_day_revaluation] # INFO # C=UpdateDBStatisticProcessListener Update Statistics Query::DEC
```

This is the line i have filtered from a file.I am trying to filter date and time from above line.
I am using:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=: " %%a in ("abc.txt")
```

to delete content before date and next i am not understanding how to filter date and time and display it

It would be helpful if someone gives me any idea to filter date and time

Comment: Please provide a small example of an input, what you try to do and your work so far.

Comment: "Helping" implies that you do some effort on your own, so show your attempts and describe what you specifically have problems with! Also read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: see `set /?` for examples of substring substitution. Another possibility (preferred, but not easy to understand for a newbee) is a `for /f` with proper tokens and delims (see `for /?`)

Comment: C:\a\controller2.log.2018-02-28:2018-02-28 20:20:59,092 # [XLProcessContextImpl.126591.end_of_day_revaluation] # INFO  # C=UpdateDBStatisticProcessListener  Update Statistics Query::DEC
This is the line i have filtered from a file.I am trying to filter date and time from above line. I am using for /F "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=:   " %%a in ("abc.txt") to delete content before date and next i am not understanding how to filter date and time and display it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are quite close. Due to the complicated syntax of the line, it's better to use two `for /f` loops (one to strip the header and the other one to split at the comma):

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=:" %%a in ("abc.txt") do (
  for /F "delims=," %%m in ("%%b") do set DateTime=%%m
)
echo %DateTime%
```

or

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=2,* delims=:" %%a in ("abc.txt") do (
  for /F "tokens=1,2" %%m in ("%%b") do set "DateTime=%%m %%n"
)
echo %DateTime%
```

(depending on what you need as time)

Comment: thank you very much, it really worked for me. Thanks for your suggeston